# How to pause audio programs in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need some Java code to pause and resume Youtube Music and Android Music, I've found that you can use a MediaController but I don't know how to implement this. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some code for this.

Comment: Can you please tell me what can you used media player or Media Controller??

Comment: I used a mediacontroller